# Borel set of subspace S = Intersection of Borel set with set S?

Tags: general-topology

In a topological space $T$ and a subspace $S$ of $T$, is every Borel set of $S$ the intersection of $S$ and a Borel set of $T$, and conversely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this follows easily from the definition and the fact it holds for open sets by definition, and you could also use transfinite induction, if you prefer that.